# String(const char*) constructor memory leak in string class

Tags: c++, string, memory

So I was trying to implement String class and I got an error saying segmentation fault. I think there is memory leak in my constructor. Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

here is the constructor code and I am not permitted to use any standard library functionality.

```
String(const char* chars){
            int i = 0;
            if(chars){
                while(chars[i]){
                    i++;
                }
            }
            len = i;
            str = new char[len - 1];
            for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
                str[j] = chars[j];
            }
        };
```

And also this is my full code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class String{
    public:
        char* str;
        int len;
        String(){
            str = new char[0];
            len = 0;
        };

        String(const char* chars){
            int i = 0;
            if(chars){
                while(chars[i]){
                    i++;
                }
            }
            len = i;
            str = new char[len - 1];
            for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
                str[j] = chars[j];
            }
        };

        String(const String& s){
            if(s.isEmpty() == false){
                len = s.len;
                str = new char[len];
                for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    str[i] = s.str[i];
                }
            }
        };
        ~String() noexcept{
            if(len > 0)
            delete[] str;
        };

        bool isEmpty() const noexcept{
            if(len == 0){
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        unsigned int length() const noexcept{
            return len;
        }

        const char* toChars() const noexcept{
            char* temp = new char[len];
            int c = 0;
            while(temp[c] != '\0'){
                temp[c] = str[c];
                c++;
            }
            return temp;
        }
};

int main()
{
    const char* chars = "Boo is snoring";
    String s;
    String t{chars};

    cout << "t.len : " << t.length() << endl << "toChar() : " << t.toChars() << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you intend `+` in the expression `str = new char[len - 1];`? You don't copy terminating zero char.

Comment: There are several flaws in your code -- one being that you do not set all your member variables in the copy constructor.  You should not care if the passed-in string is empty or not, you're supposed to make a copy.  Also you also lack a user-defined assignment operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your `String(const char* chars)` constructor is on this statement:

```cpp
str = new char[len - 1];
```

You are allocating *less* memory then you need, so your `for` loop is going out of bounds of the allocated memory.  You need to allocate *at least* `len` number of chars, not `len - 1` number of chars:

```cpp
str = new char[len];
```

If you intend `str` to be null-terminated, you need to allocate `len + 1` number of chars instead, and then insert a null terminator after the loop is finished:

```cpp
str = new char[len + 1];
for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
    str[j] = chars[j];
}
str[len] = '\0';
```

You are making a similar mistake in your `toChars()` method.  You are not null-terminating the output, which is required by the `operator<<` that you are passing the memory to afterwards:

```cpp
const char* toChars() const {
    char* temp = new char[len + 1];
    for(int c = 0; c < len; ++c){
        temp[c] = str[c];
    }
    temp[len] = '\0';
    return temp;
}
```

Note that I removed the `noexcept` on `toChars()`. This is because `new[]` is not `noexcept`, it can throw a `std::bad_alloc` exception if it can't allocate memory, which you are not catching.  `noexcept` means the method doesn't `throw` any exception at all, but that is not the case here.

There are other problems with your code, too:

- Your destructor leaks memory if `len` is 0, ie if your Default constructor is called, or your Converting constructor is called with a null/empty string.  If you call `new[]`, you need to call `delete[]`, regardless of the `len` used.
- Your Copy constructor is not initializing `str` or `len` if the `String` being copied is empty.
- In `main()`, you are not `delete[]`'ing the memory that `toChars()` returns.
- optional for this particular situation, but in general, you are missing a Copy Assignment operator.  And, since you are clearly using C++11 or later, you should also add a Move constructor and a Move Assignment operator as well.  See the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Try this instead (with no additional library functions added, per request):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class String {
    public:
        char* str = nullptr;
        unsigned int len = 0;

        String() = default;

        String(const char* chars) {
            if (chars) {
                unsigned int i = 0;
                while (chars[i]) {
                    ++i;
                }
                len = i;
                str = new char[len];
                for(int j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
                    str[j] = chars[j];
                }
            }
        }

        String(const String& s) {
            if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                len = s.len;
                str = new char[len];
                for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
                    str[i] = s.str[i];
                }
            }
        }

        ~String() noexcept {
            delete[] str;
        }

        String& operator=(const String &s) {
            if (&s != this) {
                String tmp(s);
                char *tmpstr = tmp.str;
                unsigned int tmplen = tmp.len;
                tmp.str = str;
                tmp.len = len;
                str = tmpstr;
                len = tmplen;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        bool isEmpty() const noexcept {
            return (len == 0);
        }

        unsigned int length() const noexcept {
            return len;
        }

        const char* toChars() const {
            char* temp = new char[len + 1];
            for(unsigned int c = 0; c < len; ++c) {
                temp[c] = str[c];
            }
            temp[len] = '\0';
            return temp;
        }
};

int main()
{
    String t{"Boo is snoring"};

    const char *chars = t.toChars();
    cout << "t.len : " << t.length() << endl << "toChar() : " << chars << endl; 
    delete[] chars;

    return 0;
}
```

Although, a simpler way to implement `toChars()` would look like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class String {
    public:
        char* str = nullptr;
        unsigned int len = 0;

        String() = default;

        String(const char* chars) {
            if (chars) {
                unsigned int i = 0;
                while (chars[i]) {
                    ++i;
                }
                len = i;
                str = new char[len + 1];
                for(int j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
                    str[j] = chars[j];
                }
                str[len] = '\0';
            }
        }

        String(const String& s) {
            if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                len = s.len;
                str = new char[len + 1];
                for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
                    str[i] = s.str[i];
                }
                str[len] = '\0';
            }
        }

        ~String() noexcept {
            delete[] str;
        }

        String& operator=(const String &s) {
            if (&s != this) {
                String tmp(s);
                char *tmpstr = tmp.str;
                unsigned int tmplen = tmp.len;
                tmp.str = str;
                tmp.len = len;
                str = tmpstr;
                len = tmplen;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        bool isEmpty() const noexcept {
            return (len == 0);
        }

        unsigned int length() const noexcept {
            return len;
        }

        const char* toChars() const noexcept {
            return str ? str : "";
        }
};

int main()
{
    String t{"Boo is snoring"};

    cout << "t.len : " << t.length() << endl << "toChar() : " << t.toChars() << endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However I forgot to tell you that I cannot add any other library additional. I am not permitted to use any standard library functionality. Can you please tell me other way? Thank you!

Comment: @JaeyeonPark the library functions I added don't take away from the bugs I described in your original code. But whatever, I have updated the code in my answer to only fix your bugs, no added library functions are used.

Answer (score 0):

You get crash cause you allocate len - 1 chars `new char[len - 1]`, but copy len chars `for(int j = 0; j < len; j++)` and do not copy zero-char in the end.

The first constructor should be

```
String(const char* chars) {
  len = 0;
  if (chars) {
    while (chars[len])
      len++;
  }
  str = new char[len + 1];
  for (int j = 0; j < len; j++){
    str[j] = chars[j];
  }
  str[len] = 0;
};
```

I hope you are able to update the second constructor properly.

The destructor should be

```
~String() noexcept{
  delete[] str;
}
```

I hope you are able to fix other issues.

Comment: Your constructor does not account for the possibility of `chars` being `nullptr`.  `std::strlen()` has undefined behavior for `nullptr`, and your loop goes out of bounds of `chars` when it is `nullptr`. Also, `std::copy()` should be used instead of `std::memcpy()`, `copy()` is optimized for trivial types like `char` and will likely use `memcpy()` internally.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However I forgot to tell you that I cannot add any other library additional. I am not permitted to use any standard library functionality. Can you please tell me other way? Thank you!

Comment: Ok, what's a problem, you already demonstrated the proper implementation of `strlen`.