# Why is there an error in my String class append() method?

Tags: c++, string, class

I am trying to implement a `String` class, and I found an error with my `append()` method. Could you please tell me what I did wrong with it?  I am not permitted to use any standard library functionality. I just added `<iostream>` to print output so I can check the answer.

Here is `append()`:

```cpp
void append(const String& s){
    char* temp;
    temp = new char[len+s.len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        temp[i] = str[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < s.len; i++){
        temp[len + 1] = s.str[i];
    }
    str = temp;
}
```

Here is my full code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class String{
    public:
        char* str = nullptr;
        unsigned int len = 0;

        String() = default;

        String(const char* chars){
            if(chars){
                unsigned int i = 0;
                while(chars[i]){
                    i++;
                }
                len = i;
                str = new char[len];
                for(int j = 0; j < len; j++){
                    str[j] = chars[j];
                }
            }
        };

        String(const String& s){
            if(!s.isEmpty()){
                len = s.len;
                str = new char[len];
                for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                    str[i] = s.str[i];
                }
            }
        };

        ~String() noexcept{
            delete[] str;
        };

        String& operator=(const String &s) {
            if (&s != this) {
                String tmp(s);
                char *tmpstr = tmp.str;
                unsigned int tmplen = tmp.len;
                tmp.str = str;
                tmp.len = len;
                str = tmpstr;
                len = tmplen;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        void append(const String& s){
            char* temp;
            temp = new char[len+s.len];
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                temp[i] = str[i];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < s.len; i++){
                temp[len + 1] = s.str[i];
            }
            str = temp;
        }

        bool isEmpty() const noexcept{
            return(len == 0);
        }

        unsigned int length() const noexcept{
            return len;
        }

        bool contains(const String& substring) const noexcept{
            if(find(substring)){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        int find(const String& substring) const noexcept{
            for(int i = 0; i < len - substring.len + 1; i++){
                if(str[i] == substring.str[0]){
                    for(int j = 1; j < substring.len;){
                        if(str[i + j] == substring.str[j]){
                            j++;
                            if(j == substring.len){
                                return i;
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }

        const char* toChars() const noexcept{
            char* temp = new char[len + 1];
            for(unsigned int c = 0; c < len; ++c) {
                temp[c] = str[c];
            }
            temp[len] = '\0';
            return temp;
        }
};

int main()
{
    const char* chars = "Boo is snoring1";
    const char* morechars = " and running";

    String s(chars);
    String more(morechars);
    s.append(more);

    cout << s.str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second loop should `temp[len + i]` not `temp[len + 1]`

Answer (score 3):

For starters the function append has a memory leak because the previous pointer is not deleted. And the new value of the data member `len` is not set.

```
void append(const String& s){
            char* temp;
            temp = new char[len+s.len];
            for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
                temp[i] = str[i];
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < s.len; i++){
                temp[len + 1] = s.str[i];
            }
            str = temp;
        }
```

In the second loop

```
        for(int i = 0; i < s.len; i++){
            temp[len + 1] = s.str[i];
        }
```

there is a typo. You mean

```
temp[len + i] = s.str[i];
          ^^^
```

Thirdly, you are outputting the string like a C string

```
cout << s.str << endl
```

It means that the pointed string shall have the terminating zero character.

The data members `str` and `len` shall be private data members. And the data member `len` shall have the type `size_t`.

```
    char* str = nullptr;
    unsigned int len = 0;
```

Moreover in loops you are using an index of the type `int` instead of the type `unsigned int`.

So in fact the class definition in whole is wrong.

As for the function append then it should be defined at least the following way. I assume that the pointed arrays contain strings.

```
String & append( const String &s )
{
    char* temp = new char[len + s.len + 1];

    size_t i = 0;

    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) temp[i] = str[i];
    while ( ( temp[i] = s.str[i-len] ) != '\0' ) i++;

    delete [] str;

    str = temp;
    len = len + s.len;

    return *this; 
}
```

Pay attention to that the default constructor shall allocate a memory of the size `1` and set the allocated byte to `'\0'`. In this case the data member `len` shall be set to `0`.

So check all other member functions. For example the member function `find` will have undefined behavior when the passed string has the data member `len`  equal to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your second loop is not accessing `temp` correctly.  You are using `temp[len + 1]`, but you need to use `temp[len + i]` instead.  This is why you should use more meaningful names for your variables.  `1` and `i` are not interchangable, but they are very close visually that they are easy to get confused with each other.

Also, you are not freeing the previous `str` before replacing it with the new data.  And you are not updating `len` after replacing `str`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
void append(const String& s){
    char* temp = new char[len + s.len];
    for(int idx = 0; idx < len; ++idx){
        temp[idx] = str[idx];
    }
    for(int idx = 0; idx < s.len; ++idx){
        temp[len + idx] = s.str[idx];
    }
    delete[] str;
    str = temp;
    len += s.len;
}
```

Outside of that, you have changed your `main()` since your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067994/) to print out `str` directly, but `str` is not null-terminated.  So you would need to print it out like this instead:

```cpp
int main()
{
    String s("Boo is snoring1");
    s.append(" and running");

    cout.write(s.str, s.len);
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Otherwise, go back to printing out the result of `toChars()` like I showed you earlier:

```cpp
const char *chars = s.toChars();
cout << chars << endl; 
delete[] chars;
```

Or else, you should define your own `operator<<` to print out a `String` object:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const String &s)
{
    return os.write(s.str, s.len);
}

...

cout << s << endl;
```